# how to change shipping method text from view order and emails in magento2

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods

how to show shipping method title only rather than carrier title?? 
like:
how generate this : go to myaccount=>myorders=>order information in magento2 frontend.
currently showing : "Express - Express"
expected result   : "Express"
and in emails also.

[image]